# How to create multiple excel file using loop in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, pivot-table

I have an excel file which contains four sheets, they are Type, pivot, Main, Sheet2(No name for sheet2). In Sheet(Type), i will enter some countires code in each cell from L11(Only on row). eg: DE,GB,FR., Then the program will create a new excel file(If the name already existed then it will delete and create a new one).

The new excel file contains two sheets: Main view and Overall view. 
Then it will Apply the countries filter on Pivot, Main and Sheet2 on my old excel sheet. Then copy values from Main to Main view and Sheet2 to Overall view.

My only problem is i would like to create one file for each countires. If i entered 5 countries DE;GB;FR;ES;IT then it must create 5 different excel files.
Eg: 180319-DE; 180319-GB; 180319-FR.,

But in my program it creating one new file which contains all countries data. How can i change my loop and program. For every single countries i need to run this entire program. Help me

```
Sub toptencountries()

Dim ws, ws1, ws2, wst As Worksheet
Dim table1, table2 As ListObject
Dim rng1, rng2, rng3 As Range
Dim FiltRng As Range
Dim RngArea As Range
Dim str1, str2 As Variant
Dim arr1() As String
Dim arr2() As String
Dim j, k As Long

Set wst = Sheets("Type")
LastCol = wst.Cells(wst.Rows.Count, 12).End(xlUp).Row
ReDim Preserve arr2(1 To LastCol)
For j = 1 To LastCol
    arr2(j) = wst.Cells(j, 12).Value
Next j

Filepath = ActiveWorkbook.path
FileValue = ThisWorkbook.Name
NameValue = Format(Date, "yymmdd") & "arr2" 'Need to change here
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.add
Dim path As String
Dim FSO As Object
path = Filepath & "\" & NameValue & ".xlsx"
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If FSO.FileExists(path) Then
    On Error Resume Next
        Workbooks(NameValue & ".xlsx").Close False
        Kill path
        wb.SaveAs path
        Sheets(3).Delete
    Else
    wb.SaveAs path
    Sheets(3).Delete
End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Sheets(1).Name = "Main view"
Sheets(2).Name = "Overall view"

Set ws1 = Workbooks(NameValue & ".xlsx").Worksheets("Main view")

ws1.ListObjects.add(xlSrcRange, ws1.Range("A$1:$J$1"), , xlYes).Name = "MainTable"
Set table1 = ws1.ListObjects(1)

Set ws = Workbooks(FileValue).Worksheets("Main")
Workbooks(FileValue).Worksheets("Pivot").PivotTables("Difference").PivotFields("Dealer Country Code").CurrentPage = arr2 'Need to change here
ws.PivotTables("MainTable").PivotFields("Dealer Country Code").CurrentPage = arr2 'Need to change here

With ws
    LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng1 = Range(.Range("A4"), .Range("J" & LastRow))
End With

rng1.Copy

ws1.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

Set ws2 = Sheets("Overall view")

ws2.ListObjects.add(xlSrcRange, ws2.Range("A$1:$Q$1"), , xlYes).Name = "OverallTable"
Set table2 = ws2.ListObjects(1)


Workbooks(FileValue).Activate
Sheet2.ListObjects("DataTable").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1
Sheet2.ListObjects("DataTable").Range.AutoFilter Field:=12

With ws
    LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng2 = Range(.Range("A4"), .Range("A" & LastRow))
End With

k = 1
For Each cell In rng2.Rows
    str1 = cell.Value
    ReDim Preserve arr1(k)
    arr1(k) = str1
    k = k + 1
Next cell

Sheet2.ListObjects("DataTable").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=arr1, Operator:=xlFilterValues
Sheet2.ListObjects("DataTable").Range.AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:=arr2, Operator:=xlFilterValues 'Need to change here

For Each RngArea In Sheet2.ListObjects("DataTable").Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows

If RngArea.Row > 1 Then
    If Not FiltRng Is Nothing Then
        Set FiltRng = Application.Union(FiltRng, RngArea)
    Else
        Set FiltRng = RngArea
    End If
End If

Next RngArea

If Not FiltRng Is Nothing Then
    FiltRng.Copy
    Workbooks(NameValue & ".xlsx").Sheets("Overall view").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
        xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
End If

ActiveWorkbook.Save
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: This looks like a candidate for dividing into smaller separately posted questions with minimal code to related to the distinct problem in hand. However, I will have a quick look.

Comment: Ok. I have already written a lot of notes but one thing really stands out...Are you intending on creating copies of the existing workbook (which the code is run in) as .xlsx with only data appropriate to a given country or are you intending to create new workbooks and copy the relevant data across?

Comment: I will apply filters and then copy from old book to new book for each countries.

Comment: My problem is i need to generate different workbook for different countires. Then entire progrma must run for each countires

Comment: But are you actually just filtering tables for a particular country and then want that in a new book?

Comment: yes, i am filtering for some countires only

Comment: This was as far as I was able to get at present https://pastebin.com/gi7WrZ0P, so might give you some ideas.   I think your best bet is to copy read the country codes into an array and loop that creating a copy of the existing workbook, applying the filter and then converting pivots to ranges, deleting any unwanted sheets and generally applying formatting

Comment: @qharr Thanks for your help. Showing error in this line `Set ws1 = wbNew.Worksheets("Main view")`. Not assigning the name

Comment: Did you get an out of memory  error?

Comment: It is showing subscript out of range

Comment: I checked with F8. and it is overwritting the sheet name

Comment: Silly me. Change the index(1) and (2) for names ("Sheet1") and ("Sheet2") ; the next sheet add is going to position (1) hence the overwrite...... sorry.....

Comment: I solved it. Now another error in this line `Set rng2 = Range(.Range("A4"), .Range("A" & lastRow)).Value2`. Object required error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167148/discussion-between-qharr-and-deepak).